# Either much or a lot of

Tags: adjectives

What should be used in the following sentence

Either **much** or **a lot of** and why?

> He has got many friends because he had got ________ money.

Comment: What has your research shown? Then we can give you feedback on what (if anything) is incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"A lot of" is most idiomatic in your example, because in *informal* speech we don't tend to use "much" in the affirmative.

> He had got a lot of money

We tend only to use "much" in the affirmative in *formal* speech, for example:

> There is much concern about drug addiction in the US.

Oddly, if your example were negative then either would be idiomatic in informal speech:

- He **hadn't** got much money.
- He **hadn't** got a lot of money

Comment: Indeed. _Much_ (in this sense) is a _negative polarity item_, so it tends to be found in negative sentences and questions. In its other sense as an intensifier of adjectives and adverbs it doesn't have this restriction: _I found a much nicer house_.